# Generating sequence of dates quarterly

Tags: r, date

I want to generate a sequence of dates with `one quarter` interval, with a starting date and ending date. I have below code :

```
> seq(as.Date('1980-12-31'), as.Date('1985-06-30'), by = 'quarter')
 [1] "1980-12-31" "1981-03-31" "1981-07-01" "1981-10-01" "1981-12-31"
 [6] "1982-03-31" "1982-07-01" "1982-10-01" "1982-12-31" "1983-03-31"
[11] "1983-07-01" "1983-10-01" "1983-12-31" "1984-03-31" "1984-07-01"
[16] "1984-10-01" "1984-12-31" "1985-03-31"
```

As you can see, this is not generating right sequence, as I dont understand how the date `"1981-07-01"` is coming here, I would expect `"1981-06-30"`.

Is there any way to generate such sequence correctly with quarter interval?

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The from and to dates in the question are both end-of-quarter dates so we assume that that is the general case you are interested in.

**1)** Create a sequence of yearqtr objects `yq` and then convert them to Date class.  `frac=1` tells it s to use the end of the month.  Alternately just use `yq` since that directly models years with quarters.

```
library(zoo)

from <- as.Date('1980-12-31')
to <- as.Date('1985-06-30')

yq <- seq(as.yearqtr(from), as.yearqtr(to), by = 1/4)
as.Date(yq, frac = 1)
```

giving;

```
 [1] "1980-12-31" "1981-03-31" "1981-06-30" "1981-09-30" "1981-12-31"
 [6] "1982-03-31" "1982-06-30" "1982-09-30" "1982-12-31" "1983-03-31"
[11] "1983-06-30" "1983-09-30" "1983-12-31" "1984-03-31" "1984-06-30"
[16] "1984-09-30" "1984-12-31" "1985-03-31" "1985-06-30"
```

**2)** or without any packages add 1 to `from` and `to` so that they are at the beginning of the next month, create the sequence (it has no trouble with first of month sequences) and then subtract 1 from the generated sequence giving the same result as above.

```
seq(from + 1, to + 1, by = "quarter") - 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Using the clock package and R >= 4.1:

```
library(clock)
seq(year_quarter_day(1980, 4), year_quarter_day(1985, 2), by = 1) |> 
  set_day("last") |> 
  as_date() 

# [1] "1980-12-31" "1981-03-31" "1981-06-30" "1981-09-30" "1981-12-31" "1982-03-31" "1982-06-30" "1982-09-30" "1982-12-31"
# [10] "1983-03-31" "1983-06-30" "1983-09-30" "1983-12-31" "1984-03-31" "1984-06-30" "1984-09-30" "1984-12-31" "1985-03-31"
# [19] "1985-06-30"
```

Note that this includes the final quarter.  I don't know if that was your intent.

Comment: You should be able to replace `|> calendar_widen('day') |> calendar_end('quarter')` with `|> set_day("last")` to make this a little simpler

Answer (score 0):

Different definition of "quarter". A quarter might well be (although it is not in R) 365/4 days. Look at output of :

```
as.Date('1980-12-31')+(365/4)*(0:12)
#[1] "1980-12-31" "1981-04-01" "1981-07-01" "1981-09-30" "1981-12-31" "1982-04-01" "1982-07-01" "1982-09-30"
#[9] "1982-12-31" "1983-04-01" "1983-07-01" "1983-09-30" "1983-12-31"
```

In order to avoid the days of the month from surprising you, you need to use a starting day of the month between 1 and 28, at least in non-leap years.

```
 seq(as.Date('1981-01-01'), as.Date('1985-06-30'), by = 'quarter')  
 [1] "1981-01-01" "1981-04-01" "1981-07-01" "1981-10-01" "1982-01-01" "1982-04-01" "1982-07-01" "1982-10-01"
 [9] "1983-01-01" "1983-04-01" "1983-07-01" "1983-10-01" "1984-01-01" "1984-04-01" "1984-07-01" "1984-10-01"
[17] "1985-01-01" "1985-04-01"
```